# What is the difference between set_xlim and set_xbound?

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

From the help:

**set_xlim:** Set the data limits for the xaxis.

**set_xbound:** Set the lower and upper numerical bounds of the x-axis.

That is not very clear, so let’s say that I plot something:

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(xrange(10), xrange(10))
```

Now, either I do:

```py
ax.set_xlim(2, 7)
```

or:

```py
ax.set_xbound(2, 7)
```

I do not see the difference. I can dragg the plot, all the line is ploted between 0 and 9.

Comment: [Axes.set_xbound](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xbound) uses [Axes.set_xlim](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) Take a look at the [code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py#L2355)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The bound can changes automatically, if you later plot something that is not within the bound. In contrast, limits are fixed and do not change automatically.

```
import pylab as p

t = p.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = p.sin(2*p.pi*t)

ax=p.subplot(111)
ax.plot(t, s, color='r',linewidth=1.0)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.plot(t, s+1, color='g',linewidth=1.0, label="Graph2")
p.show()


ax=p.subplot(111)
ax.plot(t, s, color='r',linewidth=1.0)
ax.set_ybound(-1,1)
ax.plot(t, s+1, color='g',linewidth=1.0, label="Graph2")
p.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, so you can get over a bound but not a limit? :-)
Thank you.

Comment: @imsc `ax.autoscale(False)` makes limits and boundaries equivalent then?

Answer (score 2):

After examining the source, we can see that `set_xbound(lower, upper)` makes a call to `set_xlim` with arguments passed like so, `self.set_xlim(sorted((lower, upper), reverse=bool(self.xaxis_inverted())), auto=None)`

So `set_xbound` is very similar to calling `set_xlim` with `auto=None` which will not change auto-scaling settings, the default when you call `set_xlim` will set `auto=False` which disables auto-scaling. This is why bounds may be altered later on by auto-scaling, as the default is to auto-scale, unless explicitly turned off (or implicitly by a method like `set_xlim`).